# rmd greek letters and accents not knitting properly

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr

I am working on adding "hats" to my Greek letters in RMarkdown to symbolize parameters. It seems that the preview/hover over mode in RMarkdown shows exactly what I want. However, when I knit the markdown file to an HTML it seems like the hat has moved and now covers the whole term rather than just my one letter. What's confusing me is clearly my code is doing what I want since that's what I can see in R, but it isn't knitting the same as this preview. Here's an example of the code:

```
 $\hat{\beta}_{0}$
```

which in R preview nicely as:

[image: what I want]

but in my HTML it knits into this:

[image: not what I want]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering this file, how does your output look?

```
---
title: "Test symbols"
date: '2021-10-23'
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amssymb} 

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

How does it look: $\hat{B} + \hat{\beta}_{3} + \hat{\Delta}_{2}$ ?
```

The hat of the capital Beta has a little offset as shown in this image.

[image: The offset in the hat of the capital Beta]

Comment: This worked!  I wonder if it's just the fact that I knit to HTML vs PDF.

Comment: @ancase Check once a time your PDF-output; but if it helped, you can accept the answer ;)